# Adding anything to body overlays background image with new white background

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm working in codepen and having an issue where any new element overwrites (or more accurately, "grafts to") my header. I double-checked for simple things like not closing the row div and such but that didn't work. Also, the new element will display a white background over my html background and when I've tried using rgba to change the opacity it hasn't helped with anything.

So,
1. How can I "unlink" subsequent elements from my header rows?
2. How can I prevent the background of subsequent elements from (visibly) overlaying the html background?

Here's the [codepen](https://codepen.io/Wolves0fTomorrow/pen/ggrKgj)

#### HTML

```html
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"/>

<html>
 <head class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 top-bar top-bar-left">
     <a href="http://codepen.io/Wolves0fTomorrow/" target="_blank">IH</a>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 top-bar top-bar-mid text-center">
     <p>Isaak Hyde Web Design</p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 top-bar top-bar-right">
     <a href="#"target="_blank">Bio</a>
     <a href="#"target="_blank">Projects</a>
     <a href="#"target="_blank">Contact</a>
   </div>
   </div>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="row bio-info">
   </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

#### CSS

```css
html { 
  background: url(http://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-  
content/uploads/2016/04/Black-     background-wallpapers-pattern-light-
texture.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.top-bar{
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: blue;
  background: gold;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.top-bar-left {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 30px;
}
.top-bar-mid { 
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 5px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.top-bar-right {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 190px;
  word-spacing: 0.5em;
}
.bio-info {
  margin-top: 50px;
}'
```

The .bio-info stuff was just to illustrate what I meant. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Sort of speechless really... I think you need to go back to your HTML handbook and start reading again from page 1. You have placed all of that content in the `<head>` tag. You can't do that... All HTML content needs to go in the `<body>`. Head is not a content header, it's the document header.

Comment: You can't put elements to the <head>. move them to `body`. You broke HTML-laws

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up `header` with `head`, you got a header outside the `body` tag, a superfluous closing `</div>`  in there and and some other basic stuff wrong

Here is a corrected version:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpKOVm

Answer (score 0):

You got your basics wrong for html as well as bootstrap.

First `<html>` encloses both `<head>` and `<body>` in that order. You put `<header>` in body not `.

In bootstrap you always enclose a `.row` in a `.container`. because `.row` has negative margin and if you do not enclose it in a `.container` then it makes content flow out of user screen and horizontal bar appears.

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5u0hw4yg/).

```css
html,body{ 
  background: url(http://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Black-background-wallpapers-pattern-light-texture.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.top-bar{
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: blue;
  background: gold;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
.top-bar-left {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 30px;
}
.top-bar-mid { 
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 5px 0px 1px 0px;
}
.top-bar-right {
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 5px 0px 0px 190px;
  word-spacing: 0.5em;
}
.bio-info {
  margin-top: 50px;
  color:white;
}
.container,.row{
  background:transparent;
}
.container{
  width:100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 top-bar top-bar-left">
      <a href="http://codepen.io/Wolves0fTomorrow/" target="_blank">IH</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 top-bar top-bar-mid text-center">
      <p>Isaak Hyde Web Design</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 top-bar top-bar-right">
      <a href="#"target="_blank">Bio</a>
      <a href="#"target="_blank">Projects</a>
      <a href="#"target="_blank">Contact</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container bio-info">
  <h1>See this works</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many tweaks, enclosed everything in body, switched `head` to `header` since the first one is for meta-tags, stylesheets, `title`, etc. added a `container-fluid` to your `header` `row`. Added a fixed `height` to your `header` components and `line-height` to vertically center text as well.

In col-md viewports would be:

[image]

Snippet below: ([external JSFiddle for resizing here](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/5mfvj9v2/10/))

```css
html {
  background: url(http://www.pixelstalk.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Black-background-wallpapers-pattern-light-texture.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
.top-bar {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: blue;
  background: gold;
  border-radius: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-bar-left {
  font-size: 22px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 41px;
  line-height: 41px;
  /* padding: 5px 0px 0px 30px; */
}
.top-bar-mid {
  font-size: 22px;
  height: 41px;
  line-height: 41px;
  /* padding: 5px 0px 1px 0px; */
}
.top-bar-right {
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 41px;
  height: 41px;
  /* padding: 5px 0px 0px 10px; */
  word-spacing: 0.5em;
}
.bio-info {
  /* margin-top: 50px; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body>
  <header class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 top-bar top-bar-left">
        <a href="http://codepen.io/Wolves0fTomorrow/" target="_blank">IH</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 top-bar top-bar-mid text-center">
        <p>Isaak Hyde Web Design</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 top-bar top-bar-right">
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Bio</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Projects</a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="row bio-info"></div>
</body>
```